# How to manually position a barcode in tcpdf

Tags: php, barcode, tcpdf

I'm trying to add some barcodes programmatically in a pdf file but I think I'm not understanding something correctly regarding positioning.Here's my code

```php
    $pdf = new TCPDF("L", "mm", array(80, 40), true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetMargins(3, 3, 3);

    // remove default header/footer
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
    $pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 12);

    foreach ($barcodes as $barcode){

        $pdf->AddPage();

        $x = $pdf->GetX();
        $y = $pdf->GetY();

        $style = array(
            'border' => true,
            'hpadding' => 'auto',
            'vpadding' => 'auto',
            'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
            'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255),
            'text' => true,
            'font' => 'helvetica',
            'fontsize' => 8,
            'stretchtext' => 4
        );
        //$pdf->Cell(30, 1, 'EAN 13', 0, 1);
        $pdf->write1DBarcode($barcode, 'EAN13', '5', '6', '60', 14, 0.4, $style, 'N');

 }
```

The result I get is like the image or in any way not even close to outputting the barcode where I'd like it to be and I have no clue why. I'd appreciate any help

[image: at 6]

if i use
    `$pdf->write1DBarcode($barcode, 'EAN13', '5', '5', '60', 14, 0.4, $style, 'N');`

[image: at 5]

There is no empty pdf page but the barcode is still really high. I'd like it to go like 1/3 from top around 14mm that's why I was trying to fiddle with the `y` variable in `write1DBarcode`

Comment: Here are the docs: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a4816d61822a4bad6e35bb441c1699aab

It says "user units", you may want to play with the x and y position some more, make the numbers more extreme and see what happens. Also, the align section might help as well.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've read the docs and user units are supposed to be the user measure units defined in the constructor of the tcpdf class. So I've set them to mm which is also the default unit and if I for example set the y to a negative number like -20 and all the way to +5 it will move accordingly at the y axis as it should. What I don't understand is at +6 and above it won't move along the axis to go lower but instead starts a new page automatically. I've been trying different values and alignments for the past 2 hours without any significant difference I'm afraid

Comment: Have you tried another unit? like "px"?

Comment: I've avoided changing the unit so far because this PDF will ultimately be printed at a label printer so I wanted to avoid the conversion between units. What's interesting is that setting autobreak to false ` $pdf->setPageOrientation("L", false, "");` will let me move it as I want without clipping issues so the problem must be in the detection of when to insert a page break

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of fiddling around I found it.

Adding

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
```

Made the autobreak behave correctly

My guess is that a bottom margin set by default that was messing around the alignment vertically that can't be set using $pdf->SetMargins. In any case problem solved for me. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use Below code

```
<?php $params = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('5027010247321', 'C39', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>true, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4), 'N'));
?>

And paste these below line where you want tcpdf baarcode 

<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="<?php echo $params; ?>" />

Visit [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flXFPbKRmUo][2]
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, to make it a good answer.